# Can't install libqt4-dev on Focal - "Package not available" despite appearing in launchpad

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, repository

I'm trying to get Geant4 up and running, and one of the required dependencies is to have libqt4-dev. Despite the fact that it appears in launchpad [(link)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/qt4-x11), I keep on getting the following error:

- ```
  Package libqt4-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
  is only available from another source
  ```
- ```
  E: Package 'libqt4-dev' has no installation candidate
  ```

I've tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade, as well as following a few similar threads from 2017, but nothing has worked yet. I was able to install other libraries such as libx11-dev or libxerces-c-dev, so I don't think its a repository issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doth Debian and Ubuntu have dropped QT4 from new releases, superseded by QT5.

The `libqt4-dev` package was dropped from Ubuntu after 19.10 and is indeed not in the 20.04 repositories. QT4 remains in older releases of Ubuntu.

If Geant4 requires obsolete/dropped software like libqt4, consider filing a bug report with the upstream developers. Alternately, you can use Ubuntu 18.04 which still has a full QT4 stack in the repositories.

Comment: when i typed:sudo apt-get install libqt5-dev, it was prompted: E: Unable to locate package libqt5-dev

Comment: @MianQi you seem to be talking about a different problem. Please open a new question instead of confusing this one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the repository by running the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I tried a `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y` afterward and got an error message including `404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]`. And afterward `sudo apt install libqt4-dev` still gave `E: Unable to locate package libqt4-dev
`. I am on Ubuntu 21.04, and according to some searching that may be the problem.

Comment: @TannerLegvold They might have removed the repository? I will check if it still works for me

Answer (score 0):

That's from your link, everything is said unfortunately.

[image: Not available]